# How to use Collection API?

Tags: java, oop, collections

I have  a packet having fields :

Root Level : CHOICE

Level 1 : SET

Level 2 : SEQUENCE , CHOICE

Note : CHOICE :- You can have one available fields.

```
SET :- Fields can be in any order.

SEQUENCE : Fields are in specific order.
```

Assume each field has a unique id for specific level.

I want to read and then put in one one Collection API.

Can anybody suggest how to use MAP, SET or List in an efficient way?

Comment: Sorry mate, I couldn't get a hint of what you're trying to say!

Comment: Your *packet full of fields*, is it XML, JSON, binary? Is it hierarchical and you want to create a model for that packet/document?

Comment: "packet full of fields" made me think of a hovercraft full of eels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ability to use a structure in an efficient way is entirely dependent upon how you wish to access the data.  If you want to be able to find a specific item according to a key, use a HashMap.  If you want to be able to have an arbitrary list of items, use ArrayList.  If you wish to be able to both access a specific item according to a key and be able to iterate all items like a list, use LinkedHashMap.

Though from what you're describing about a set of CHOICE, it seems to me you're talking about an enumerator.  Enumerators are essentially static sets, and unless you intend on modifying your choices dynamically, I would suggest you use this rather than a Set.

Answer (score 2):

SET > [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) ([Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html))
SEQUENCE > [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) ([Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html))
CHOICE doesn't really have a mapping in the Collection API, but you could use [`AtomicReference`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).